# How do invalidate a stylesheet for the rest of the page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I'm working on a project, where the site header needs to be the same as the wordpress blog header. The header itself has its own set of styles I don't want to influence the rest of the body. Is there a way of invalidating the old style sheet and applying a new one part way down the page?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmIIF.jpg)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: No. Probably the best solution for you is to copy header-specific CSS style to your own stylesheet used for your tool page.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to code properly so that the header uses its own styles while the rest of the site uses its own.

Ideal is to enclose the header in another div and make those rules work for that div only by mentioning that `div` before each other style, like e.g. if you enclose header in the new `div` named `header` like this: `<div id="header">`, then:

```
#header .oldclass{ /* styles here */ }
```

Rest I can suggest better after seeing your current site or complete code.